# Проблема с get-запросом (насколько я понял - сертификат)

Tags: python, requests

В результате get-запроса на url одного из ВУЗов получаю ошибку `requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='abit.lunn.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(9, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3874)')))` Нашел на стеке совет, что можно обновить сертификаты, запустив файл Install Certificates.command, но ошибка не прошла. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно пофиксить. Буду благодарен!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: попрбуйте так: `requests.get('https://example.com', verify=False)`